# jQuery execute script only for url and not this url but url has the same work in both url

Tags: jquery

I would like to execute some script only for http://win-23ookphjfn0/Previsions/Pages/default.aspx and not for http://win-23ookphjfn0/abc/Pages/Les_Previsions.aspx

that script doesn't seem to function.

```
var url = location.pathname;
if (url.indexOf('Previsions') >= 0) {
//script here
}
```

how should i go?

Comment: Is your script located inside a master page?

Comment: nope it is located in a js file

Comment: I just tried it inside one of my pages and it worked, which leads me to believe that location.pathname might be getting the path of the js file rather than the page.  Can you step through and see what value the url var is getting?

Comment: Did none of the answers below work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your url is corrrect and '/Previsions/' should me there in the url so try this-

```
var url = location.pathname;
if (url.indexOf('/Previsions/') >= 0) {
alert();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = location.pathname;
if (url.indexOf('Previsions') >= 0) {
window.location = url;
}
```

u can relocate the url by this,

Comment: i do not whish to redirect the page but execute a script only for http://win-23ookphjfn0/Previsions/ but not http://win-23ookphjfn0/abc/Pages/Les_Previsions.aspx

Comment: $.getScript('ur_js_file.js', function(){  
  alert('script loaded.');
});

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
var url = window.pathname;
if (url.indexOf('Previsions') >= 0) {
//script here
}
```

window.pathname should give you the url in the browser window, rather than the file where the script is housed.

Here is an alternative to window.pathname as well:

```
document.location.href
```